# Options to deploy a proxy for a Digital Ocean MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, proxy, cloud

As the title says, in my job there is a MongoDB in Digital Ocean and now we are also using GCP as we need something more robust.

I already manage to deploy a S2S VPN between GCP and DO but I am failing to find an option for a proxy that I could deploy in DO and be able to access from my GCP resources.

The reason I have to do this is because DO Mongo works with a domain and cannot be reached from GCP without exposing to the internet and even then I have experience connectivity loss.